# Remove 'Create New Case' button from Community

Tags: permissions, page-layout, button, community

I have sandbox where community is enabled, and Case tab added to the community. When we click on Case tab list of Cases getting displayed and also a button on top with name 'Create New Case'. My question is can i hide this button or rename it or remove it from Community?

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy way to remove the new button.  You could use sidebar components to add javascript to the page, but this is not recommended as its highly dependent on SF html output and could change at anytime, thus breaking your layout.

My question is why do you want to do this.  If you have a group of users that you do not want creating Cases, then why not just restrict them to view access, and not give them create access?

So why not just modify the profile for the group of community members so they don't have create access on the case, which will solve the issue as they will no longer see the 'New' button as they don't have the permissions to do so.

Comment: I was able to remove create privileges by cloning the profile "Customer Community User" to a new profile. You can then uncheck the "Create" permission on Cases.

Footnote: with the upcoming changes to Salesforce1 and Lightning, I'd no longer suggest Javascript injection techniques.

Comment: I agree, I would not suggest Javascript injection either, which is why I warned against using it.  Even without the new Lightning Experience, I would say, stay  away from it.